# Execute C code in an atomic way

Tags: c, atomic

I would like to know if it is possible to execute two consecutive instructions in C, in an atomic way. This means that I don't want any other process executing in the operating system (Linux) consume processing time while this instructions are executing.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't because your process will share CPU according to Linux scheduler. You can increase process priority to be _quasi_ real-time but you can't be _sure_. Of course unless such instructions can be made atomic at CPU level...

Comment: What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve? You must have a reason to want to prevent anyone else from running other than preventing them from running because it sounds like fun. The operating system most likely provides you tools for that.

Comment: One way is to use inline assembly in user space, which is architecture-specific, and wrap those instructions that disables and enables interrupts. Another way is to execute those instructions in kernel via a kernel driver. You have facilities in kernel that gives you atomicity.

Comment: The problem is that i'm trying to figure out what happens when I execute twice the instruction:`clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&ts2);´ Trying to measure current time with a precission of nanoseconds. The problem is that I have a differencen of almost 4 us between both instructions, that it's too much for what I'm trying to do. In addition, this time changes between consecutive executions, so I suspect that other processes in the system are consuming this time.

Comment: `clock_gettime` is definitely not an instruction. It's a system call that involves saving quite a lot of state, an address space change and then a bunch of work done inside the kernel. 4us sounds like a lot, but it's not impossible that it is that expensive. Especially if the underlying hardware the operating system talks to is bad (which it is on most PCs). It's likely though that if some other process was running, you'd be seeing delays on the order of 10ms rather than just 4us. Is this delay consistent? You're quite unlikely to be preempted more than once in a very long while.

Comment: I just did an experiment. The time between two consecutive calls to `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)` on my machine exceeds 150ns in 0.01% of the calls. The longest delay is around 300us when the machine doesn't do much else on the 12 CPUs, but when I hit it with a load on all CPUs the longest delay jumps up to 10ms (the default time slice on this system). Basically this is the noise level you have to live with in measurements on a modern operating system on modern hardware. You can do better inside the kernel, but not much better. Modern memory architectures are mostly unpredictable.

Comment: Ok then. Thank you very much for all answers. I was planning to use this time measures to implement RTLS using TDOA(Time Difference of Arrival) techniques. But of course, I need a reliable time source and syncronization between nodes. I should find another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible for one process to block everyone else. That would be pretty bad for a multi-user system and even on single user systems it has quite horrible failure modes.

You can increase your priority levels, but even then you will be preempted by interrupts and system level processes.

The best you can do to prevent others from running is using locks which makes other cooperating processes sleep when acquiring the same lock.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The operating system is free to interrupt your program at any point. The C programming language does not specify how threads of execution are scheduled and provides no means of influencing this scheduling.

The best that you can get is to specify that two specific threads of execution cannot interleave at certain points. This however requires synchronization on both sides. That is, you can say this code in thread A should not interleave with that code in thread B, but you cannot say this code in thread A should not interleave with *anything* else.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do what you want is in the kernel space. It is possible to handle an interruption in a kernel driver and suspend other processes. But doing this suppose you have really good reasons to do that and very good knowledge of kernel hacking.